# Excel VBA Code for Multiple Rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have got VBA for Appending HTML Tag. I want that code work for multiple Rows like J2:J50000

Code is like

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim newStrng As String
    Dim word As Variant
    Dim parTag As String, endParTag As String
    Dim dateCounter As Long

    parTag = "<p>" '
    endParTag = "</p>" '
    With Worksheets("TextSheet") '
        For Each word In Split(.Range("A1").Text, " ") '<-- Range should be like A1:A50000
            If Len(word) - Len(Replace(word, "/", "")) = 2 Then
                dateCounter = dateCounter + 1
                If dateCounter > 1 Then newStrng = newStrng & endParTag
                newStrng = newStrng & parTag & word
            Else
                newStrng = newStrng & " " & word
            End If
        Next word
        If dateCounter > 1 Then newStrng = newStrng & endParTag
        .Range("A2").Value = LTrim(newStrng)
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the range into a vba array, and then looping through that:

```
Sub main()
    Dim newStrng As String
    Dim word As Variant
    Dim usedCell As Variant
    Dim inputArray() As Variant
    Dim outputArray() As Variant
    Dim parTag As String, endParTag As String
    Dim dateCounter As Long
    Dim i As Long

    parTag = "<p>" '
    endParTag = "</p>" '
    With Worksheets("TextSheet") '
        inputArray = .Range("A1:A50000").Value
        ReDim outputArray(1 To UBound(inputArray, 1))
        For i = 1 To UBound(inputArray, 1)
            dateCounter = 0
            newStrng = ""
            For Each word In Split(inputArray(i, 1), " ")
                If Len(word) - Len(Replace(word, "/", "")) = 2 Then
                    dateCounter = dateCounter + 1
                    If dateCounter > 1 Then newStrng = newStrng & endParTag
                    newStrng = newStrng & parTag & word
                Else
                    newStrng = newStrng & " " & word
                End If
            Next word
            If dateCounter > 1 Then newStrng = newStrng & endParTag
            outputArray(i) = LTrim(newStrng)
        Next i
        .Range("B1:B50000").Value = Application.Transpose(outputArray)
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub main2()
    Dim newStrng As String
    Dim word As Variant
    Dim usedCell As Variant
    Dim dataArr As Variant
    Dim parTag As String, endParTag As String
    Dim dateCounter As Long
    Dim i As Long

    parTag = "<p>" '
    endParTag = "</p>" '
    With Worksheets("TextSheet") '
        dataArr = .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value
        For i = 1 To UBound(dataArr, 1)
            dateCounter = 0
            newStrng = ""
            For Each word In Split(dataArr(i, 1), " ")
                If Len(word) - Len(Replace(word, "/", "")) = 2 Then
                    dateCounter = dateCounter + 1
                    If dateCounter > 1 Then newStrng = newStrng & endParTag
                    newStrng = newStrng & parTag & word
                Else
                    newStrng = newStrng & " " & word
                End If
            Next word
            If dateCounter > 1 Then newStrng = newStrng & endParTag
            dataArr(i, 1) = LTrim(newStrng)
        Next i
        .Range("B1").Resize(UBound(dataArr, 1)).Value = dataArr
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I tested it with no problems. Be sure to have all wanted cells to be processed in column "A" and you'll get their processed results in column "B" corresponding row. If you need different input and/or output columns than "A" and "B" then simply adopt proper references in `.Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value` for input column and `.Range("B1").Resize(UBound(dataArr, 1)).Value = dataArr` for output

Comment: @ShantanuMahajan, did you get through it?

Comment: @ShantanuMahajan, it'd be nice of you giving proper feedbacks at people trying at helping you. thank you

Comment: Sorry for late reply Actually I was busy with something else. When I Run this Macro function it is giving me the Runtime error.

Comment: I don't have line numeration, please specify the line text and the exact error (number and description) thank you

Comment: It is giving me error like this --- Runtime Error '13':Type mismatch

Comment: please, type in the text of the line throwing that error

Comment: As I am debugging it, After the line  For i = 1 To UBound(dataArr, 1) it throws an error of Type Mismatch

Comment: you mean line `For i = 1 To UBound(dataArr, 1) ` is highlighted? Or the next one (i.e. `dateCounter = 0`)?

Comment: From next one (i.e dateCounter = 0)

Comment: then you're not getting it: `dateCounter` is declared as of `Long` type, and assignin it a `0` can't rise any error at all! Run the macro, when it errors out click "Debug" and see what line is highlighted yellow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127093/discussion-between-shantanu-mahajan-and-user3598756).